# prevent users from opening react app in multiple browser tabs

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about opening react app in multiple tabs in browser.

How could I prevent that? Is there any library or should I try to store (in cookies, localStorage?) some unique id of tab and check if a new tab opens and then close it?

Comment: There is nothing you can do to prevent a user from opening multiple tabs and opening the same url in every tab. You could store a cookie in localStorage to see if they opened another tab or not, but that won't work for different browsers or incognito mode.

Comment: You could take this a step further and track the session on the server ensuring that only one session is active